# HTML Add extended border at bottom of image and write text on it

Tags: html, css

This is my css. I want to add extended border to each image and write text in that space. How can I do that?

```
.column {
    -ms-flex: 50%; /* IE 10 */
    flex: 50%;
    padding: 0 4px;
}
.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE 10 */
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE 10 */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 2px;
}


.column img {
        margin-top: 12px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border: 2px solid;
}
```

This is my HTML. Everything is working fine, I just want to add text in that extended border at bottom:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/87/e9/38/87e938ab69a614cddb14a6866b2478d0.jpg" onclick="app();" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/564x/32/03/4f/32034f6da33f2932d88c6d6db7fa117a.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/96/e6/54/96e654398c4b2cd7afc03410d636dbea.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/4e/78/48/4e7848375fa721845f4986006229555a.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/1a/b0/d4/1ab0d4ef04e3e789396ae744f626c68a.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/41/fd/31/41fd312937d0fd0e864d8fdd53f055ba.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/06/98/94/069894936419220407b4b11edfca833d.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/18/8b/bf/188bbfa47af6b445cf2a5a1869c90566.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: When you say "extra border", do you mean "extra space" where you can write captions? Something like "card" or if we imagine old polaroid photos with the white space below photo?

Comment: yes something like card to add text.

Comment: with proper wrapping.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
figcaption {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Got this as my answer. thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 proposes a [`<figure>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) HTML tag for this purpose:

```css
figure {
  width: 25vw
}

img {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://html.com/wp-content/uploads/flamingo.jpg" alt="flamingo">
  <figcaption><i>fig. 1</i> A pink flamingo.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

So you'd result with this:

```css
.column {
  -ms-flex: 50%;
  /* IE 10 */
  flex-basis: 45%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  /* IE 10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* IE 10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 2px;
}

.column figure {
  margin-top: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 2px solid;
}

img {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <figure><img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/87/e9/38/87e938ab69a614cddb14a6866b2478d0.jpg" onclick="app();">
      <figcaption><i>fig. 1</i> A picture caption.</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure><img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/564x/32/03/4f/32034f6da33f2932d88c6d6db7fa117a.jpg">
      <figcaption><i>fig. 2</i> A picture caption.</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure><img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/96/e6/54/96e654398c4b2cd7afc03410d636dbea.jpg">
      <figcaption><i>fig. 3</i> A picture caption.</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure><img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/4e/78/48/4e7848375fa721845f4986006229555a.jpg">
      <figcaption><i>fig. 4</i> A picture caption.</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <figure><img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/1a/b0/d4/1ab0d4ef04e3e789396ae744f626c68a.jpg">
      <figcaption><i>fig. 5</i> A picture caption.</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure><img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/41/fd/31/41fd312937d0fd0e864d8fdd53f055ba.jpg">
      <figcaption><i>fig. 6</i> A picture caption.</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure><img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/06/98/94/069894936419220407b4b11edfca833d.jpg">
      <figcaption><i>fig. 7</i> A picture caption.</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure><img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/18/8b/bf/188bbfa47af6b445cf2a5a1869c90566.jpg">
      <figcaption><i>fig. 8</i> A picture caption.</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, if that's what you're asking.

```
.column {
    -ms-flex: 50%; /* IE 10 */
    flex: 50%;
    padding: 0 4px;
}
.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE 10 */
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE 10 */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 2px;
}


 ul li {
        margin-top: 12px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 2px solid;
        list-style: none;
    }


<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<LINK rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">

    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/87/e9/38/87e938ab69a614cddb14a6866b2478d0.jpg" onclick="app();" style="width:100%">
            <p>Something</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/564x/32/03/4f/32034f6da33f2932d88c6d6db7fa117a.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <p>Something else</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/96/e6/54/96e654398c4b2cd7afc03410d636dbea.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <p> </p>
        </li>
    <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/4e/78/48/4e7848375fa721845f4986006229555a.jpg" style="width:100%">

    <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/1a/b0/d4/1ab0d4ef04e3e789396ae744f626c68a.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/41/fd/31/41fd312937d0fd0e864d8fdd53f055ba.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/06/98/94/069894936419220407b4b11edfca833d.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/18/8b/bf/188bbfa47af6b445cf2a5a1869c90566.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </ul
  </div>  
</div>

</HTML>
```

Comment: generally Im getting two column in mobile view. Here i am getting only one column.